# Titanium with Alloy Material Design

Tags: android, titanium, material-design, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

first of all sorry for my english!
I readed this: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/07/understanding-the-android-material-theme/ following step by step to use Material Theme on my **Android** app! It works fine with Titanium Classic but doesn't with Alloy Framework. Are there differencies between the two approaches?

With Alloy i just don't see any differencies with or without theme.

The error I received is :

```
[ERROR] Detected legacy "/platform" directory in project directory. 
[ERROR] Please move the "/platform" directory to "/app/platform" for Alloy 1.8.0 or later. [ERROR] Alloy compiler failed
```

But moving /platform to /app/platform it still not working

Thank you, Luca

EDIT:

I found a possible fix. In my tiapp.xml (generated with TiShadow), i have:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  **POSITION ONE**

  <manifest android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.5.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
       //long list of uses-permission
    <uses-feature android:name='android.hardware.microphone' android:required="false" />
       //long list of uses-features
    <application>
      <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true"/>
    </application>
    </manifest>
    **POSITION TWO**
</android>
```

I have to insert:

```
<manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Appcelerator"> </application>
</manifest>
```

If i insert it on **POSITION ONE**, it doesn't work (totally ignored); but if i insert it on **POSITION TWO** it works fine.

I tried more times with the same result. Could someone give me an explanation? :confused:

Comment: does it show any error? please post your code here.

Comment: No one error, just the colors don't change.
I followed step by step the example in the guide in a blank Titanium+TiShadow+Alloy Project

Comment: Sorry, I received this error:

[ERROR] Detected legacy "/platform" directory in project directory.
[ERROR] Please move the "/platform" directory to "/app/platform" for Alloy 1.8.0 or later.
[ERROR] Alloy compiler failed.
...

But moving /platform to /app/platform it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please edit your question by adding your answer into it as it is not an answer.

Now coming to your query, the reason behind two positions is that:

**application** tag must come inside **manifest** tag, otherwise it will be ignored.

Since **manifest** tag is the topmost tag, that's why Pos 1 is ignored and rest below **manifest** tag is considered within **manifest**, so that's why Pos 2 works.

Now, you already have the **application** tag below **uses-feature** and all you need is to add the **android:theme="@style/Theme.Appcelerator"** attribute to **application** tag.

So your final **android** tag in **tiapp.xml** will look like this:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <manifest android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.5.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />

    <uses-feature android:name='android.hardware.microphone' android:required="false" />

    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Appcelerator">
      <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true"/>
    </application>

  </manifest>
</android>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI the solution marked as the correct answer no longer works as Appcelerator will remove the /res/values/ directory during build and error that it can't find your newly created theme. As of now, put your theme.xml in app/platform/android/.